# how do i make a django choicefield accept both preset choices and the addition of a new choice by a user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have the following  code in my model

```
MY_CATEGORIES = (
('A', 'meal'),
('B', 'personal'),
)

######### and the model
class Job(models.Model):
    category= models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=MY_CATEGORIES,default='A')
```

i would like to make the list of choices extendable, i.e. if the choice a user wants is not present they can write a new one and in future it will be available as a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `Category` model and populate the initial values `meal` and `personal` through a [fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/). And when a user enters a category that doesn't exists you create a new object.

**EDIT**:

Basically you create two models instead of one, `Job` and `Category`, whereas `Job` has a `ForeignKey` to `Category`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Job(models.Model):
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

You don't have to create any tables on your own, syncdb will take care of it on the next run.

Then you create a fixture and put it into the `fixtures` directory of your app. This will assure that these two entries are always present:

```
[
    {
        "model": "myapp.category",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "name": "meal"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "myapp.category",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "name": "personal"
        }
    }
]
```

Note, that you can also enter these entries through the admin of the Category model when you created one. Then you can use dumpdata to, well, dump the data, so you don't have to write that by hand.

The view/form logic to create new category instances has of course to be written. The form should be pretty much standard, a `ModelForm` for the `Job` model, plus an additional field to enter new categories should do the job. So the only thing you have to put some thought into, is the validation of creating new entries. The form will automatically pick up new entries, as the default of a `ModelChoiceField` is to include all entries.

Comment: so i have to create some code to check whether the category exists? will that  involve creating new tables in the database?  and how will i be able to provide the same category in future? is it by qerrying the categories using a unique filter?